# Pytesseract Incorrectly Recognizes 'Z' as '7' in License Plate OCR

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-tesseract

I'm working on a license plate recognition system using Python and OpenCV. The system extracts and processes the license plate area from an image or video frame, and then uses pytesseract for optical character recognition (OCR). However, I'm facing an issue where pytesseract often misinterprets the letter 'Z' as the number '7'.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as opencv
import pytesseract

class LicensePlateProcessor:
    @staticmethod
    def process_license_plate(frame, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        # ... [initial steps: cropping, grayscaling, blurring, thresholding, inverting] ...

        # Find contours, calculate areas, and extract the largest contour
        contours, _ = opencv.findContours(inverted_license_plate, opencv.RETR_TREE, opencv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        areas = np.array([opencv.contourArea(contour) for contour in contours])
        max_index = np.argmax(areas)
        contour = contours[max_index]

        # Calculate moments for centroid, and crop around the centroid
        moments = opencv.moments(contour)
        m00 = np.array(moments['m00'])
        m10 = np.array(moments['m10'])
        m01 = np.array(moments['m01'])
        cx, cy = np.divide([m10, m01], m00, out=np.zeros_like([m10, m01]), where=m00 != 0)
        cx, cy = cx.astype(int), cy.astype(int)
        height, width = inverted_license_plate.shape[:2]
        offset = np.array([np.add(np.floor_divide(width, 2.961), 30), np.floor_divide(height, 4.972)]).astype(np.int32)
        rect_top_left = np.clip([cx - offset[0], cy - offset[1]], 0, None)
        rect_bottom_right = np.clip([cx + offset[0], cy + offset[1]], None, inverted_license_plate.shape[::-1])
        cropped_image = inverted_license_plate[rect_top_left[1]:rect_bottom_right[1], rect_top_left[0]:rect_bottom_right[0]]

        # OCR using pytesseract on the cropped image
        recognized_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(lang='en', cropped_image, config='--psm 13 --oem 3')

        return recognized_text

# Example usage
frame = opencv.imread('license_plate_image.jpg')
recognized_plate = LicensePlateProcessor.process_license_plate(frame, x1, y1, x2, y2)
print(recognized_plate)
```

I've tried different preprocessing steps like grayscaling, blurring, thresholding, and inverting the image before passing it to pytesseract. Despite these, 'Z' often gets recognized as '7'

Edit: Here is the cropped output image I've been processing.

[image]

For some odd reason, tesseract finds Z to be more likely correlated to the number 7, than the actual letter. It seems I will have to train tesseract based on this standard font, whose name I don't know.

Comment: Have you bothered searching for denoising functions? [ask]

Comment: It is unclear what you are requesting - what's the "pixel noise" you are trying to remove? What's the image output you are looking for?

Comment: Post an example image

Answer (score 1):

I have an easy solution for your problem. Use something like "thresholding segmentation" or "contrast segmentation" to extract symbols from the image. You will no longer have one image with all the symbols, but rather n images, each containing a single symbol.

Then, pass these images to the OCR one by one. Now, Pytesseract won't attempt to read the entire text at once; instead, it will classify each symbol separately.

Next, create your own neural network - a simple classifier with only two classes: "7" and "Z". Whenever Pytesseract returns a 7 or Z, re-evaluate that symbol using your NN, which is specifically trained for this issue. This solution might not be the fastest in terms of program execution, but it's quite straightforward and should effectively solve your problem.

The best solution would be of course to use paid OCR, like that one from Google (which works really good), or to write your own OCR from scratch. But, if you need a simple solution just to read license plates, this might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In most countries the fonts used for number plates are heavily regulated. I would suggest getting a reasonably large sample of the number plates, normalising them and then training Tesseract for this specific application.

See https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/tess4/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html for a really good tutorial on how to train Tesseract.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers mentioned, it is better to go with fine-tuning tesseract for this font.

On the other hand, in any case, the recognized plate image is not clear enough to be used for the OCR step.

If I use the image you provided with `pytesseract`, I get `'786*PTBII` as a result.

[image]

From that, especially the leading `'` and last `II` characters, one can notice that the white regions on the left & right borders cause false character recognitions. In short, the image has to be processed further.
Some general OCR tricks:

- Crop the image tighter to remove non-character blobs

[image]

- Apply morphological opening filter (erode + dilate) to remove the remaining non-character blobs

`cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8))`

[image]

- Apply Gaussian blur to remove pixel artifacts

`cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7), 0)`

[image]

- Downscale the image and extend it

`cv2.copyMakeBorder(cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5), 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])`

[image]

- Use appropriate tesseract parameters
- Page segmentation modes 6 or 7

  - 6: Assume a single uniform block of text.
  - 7: Treat the image as a single text line.
- Use character whitelist (`tessedit_char_whitelist`) to help tesseract the expected characters, i.e. digits & capital letters.

-> And the **final result**: `Z86PTB`

Keep in mind that the tricks above will take you only so far. The results will be brittle and you will find yourself trying to tune the preprocessing parameters for each edge case. Without training / fine-tuning your own model for this font, it is hard to get reliable results out-of-the-box from tesseract.

*Also, [here's the documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) from tesseract on how to improve output quality explaining more tricks like used above.*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that basically involves processing each individual character. You need to crop each glyph and then feed it to tesseract. There's a lot of noise, so you need to clean the image first. The cleaning step I chose involves filtering blobs based on a *minimum size* and a *maximum aspect ratio*. After a noisy blob has been identified, I use the flood-fill operation to fill it with black and "erase" it, leaving only valid blobs.

After the image has been cleaned, I get the bounding rectangle of every valid glyph and use these coordinates to crop each character and pass it to tesseract. Once you OCR each character you can build the final string. Even though you can write the whole logic in one big loop, I've chosen to break the process in two individual loops for the sake of clarity - the first loop cleans the image and the second crops each glyph out for OCR.

This is the first part:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract  # tesseract (previous installation)

# Set image path:
directoryPath = "D://opencvImages//"
imagePath = directoryPath + "binaryPlate.png"

# Load image:
inputImage = readImage(imagePath)

inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# To grayscale:
binaryImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get dimensions:
imageHeight, imageWidth = binaryImage.shape[0:2]

# Find the external contours only:
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    currentArea = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Filter area:
    minArea = 1300

    # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Get aspect ratio:
    aspectRatio = rectHeight / rectWidth

    # Filter aspect ratio:
    maxAspectRatio = 2.50

    if not ((currentArea > minArea) and (aspectRatio < maxAspectRatio)):
        # Get contour centroid:
        cx = int(int(boundRect[0]) + 0.5 * int(boundRect[2]))
        cy = int(int(boundRect[1]) + 0.5 * int(boundRect[3]))
        # Fill contour with black at centroid:
        cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, None, (cx, cy), (0, 0, 0))

    # Show stats:
    print(i, currentArea, aspectRatio)
```

This is an animation of the filtering process, you see each noisy blob disappearing:

[image]

What happens if I feed this image (which seems totally fine) to tesseract?

> Tesseract's Output: *786 PTB.*

Yeah, not great. Let's add the second part:

```
# Once the image is filtered, process each character,
# Get contours again, on the cleaned image:
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get bounding boxes and sort them left to right on the x-axis:
boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
boundingBoxes = sorted(boundingBoxes, key=lambda b: b[0], reverse=False)

# Setting up tesseract:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'  # for Windows
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 13'

# Store string here:
outString = ""

# Process individual characters:
for boundRect in boundingBoxes:
    # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
    rectX = boundRect[0]
    rectY = boundRect[1]
    rectWidth = boundRect[2]
    rectHeight = boundRect[3]

    # Crop character:
    currentCrop = binaryImage[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]

    # Set margin:
    m = 5
    currentCrop = cv2.copyMakeBorder(currentCrop, m, m, m, m, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])

    # Set new scale:
    scalePercent = 50
    width = int(currentCrop.shape[1] * scalePercent / 100)
    height = int(currentCrop.shape[0] * scalePercent / 100)
    newSize = (width, height)

    # Resize:
    currentCrop = cv2.resize(currentCrop, newSize, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # Show image:
    cv2.imshow("Current Crop", currentCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # OCR character:
    currentChar = pytesseract.image_to_string(currentCrop, config=custom_config)

    # Slice first character and append to string:
    outString += currentChar[0:1]

# Show recognized text:
print("Text is: " + outString)
```

The process is essentially to extract the bounding rectangles on the new binary image. However, there's no guarantee that the bounding rectangles will be ordered. This is an easy fix, as they only need to be sorted from small to largest on the horizontal axis. Once the rectangles are sorted, just use the information to crop the character. Additionally, it seems to add a "margin" and resize the image helps tesseract to parse the text better.

Here's an animation of the crop process:

[image]

The final output is:

```
Text is: Z86pTB
```

**Final Thoughts**

Tesseract is garbage - that's the reality of it. If you want any small sense of robustness, you should implement your own text classifier. Even a small `SVM` will do better with the kind of processing suggestions you have been given. I wouldn't really on tesseract for anything, really. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom Neural Network with Candidate Elimination

I solved a similar problem for recognizing painted on/vinyl numbers on trailers. Without images given in your question, I can only give you the outline of how to solve the problem.

**[1]** Identify candidate letters and bounding boxes. We used a box filter at different sizes and counted pixels that had the a color close to the color of the letters and close to the background color. Ours was white letters on a blue background.

**[2]** Disqualify candidates that are not near other candidates or were radically different sizes for close candidates. Pick the best remaining candidates. We knew to look for 7 letters in a horizontal-ish line that had similar sized bounding boxes

**[3]** Black/white threshold each remaining letter, scale down and feed into a neural network. We trained a 10x10 pixel neural network to identify 0-9 A-Z with a confidence output. We saved low confidence letters for further training especially in production so that the neural network would get better.

We got amazing results and eventually could pick numbers through mud and dirt on the trailers with good accuracy and almost no incorrect positive matches.